# 3 monitors using built in graphics & Nvidia card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I am struggling with this.  I have tried multiple things that I have found on the net with no luck.  I have built in Intel graphics on my motherboard.  I have DVI/VGA/HDMI ports on my motherboard.  I have configured BIOS to allow both of them to work.  I have had this working just fine on Windows 7 & Windows 10 here at work.  I have decided that I want to get away from Windows on my desktop PC here at work and switch over to linux.  For anything needed with Windows, I would have a VM for that.

Anyway, I have a Nvidia graphics card and for the life of me, I am unable to get this working.  If you use the factory generic driver, and go to the display settings, you see all 3 monitors, but only the 2 on the Nvidia card will actually work.  It is very jumpy, mouse pointer hides when moving...etc.  If you install any of the open source Nvidia drivers then it gets rid of the jumpiness and the mouse pointer from hiding.  If you go to the display properties in the nvidia panel application then it doesn't see the monitor after you pick the nvidia driver....nor does it in the normal display properties in ubuntu.

I have a mini hdmi out port on my graphics card with the 2 dvi's....I figured I would be smart and run all 3 monitors off of one card...no, that doesn't work either....it shows the monitor but it will not enable it in the nvidia app....

This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have identical configuration. I had to set some things in BIOS exactly as you said to have three monitors. With NVIDIA there was no way for me to setup three monitors working. I gave up and I am using open source NVIDIA driver - nouveau with intel driver for the onboard adapter. It seemed to me as NVIDIA priprietary driver will not cowork with any other driver.

I also had problems not showing the picture on monitor connected to Intel onboard adapter. I changed some BIOS settings and then the picture on the third monitor appeared. Unfortunately, I don't remember the BIOS setting and I don't have the access to that computer right now. I can check tommorow when I get to that computer, but I don't think I will remember, which BIOS setting it was.

Comment: So you did manage to get yours working?  Are you talking about the Binary driver that comes built in and allows you to pick it by going to Additional Drivers, or are you talking about a different one? I am using the Nvidia drivers that are available when you go to the Additional Software and not having any luck.  Yes, mine will show a black screen with a blinking cursor on the monitor hooked up to the internal intel graphics.  Also, how are you picking your intel driver?  I tried to download and install this, but after I reboot I get a black screen with blinking https://01.org/linuxgraphics

Comment: So I took your advice, and went into BIOS.  I told it to make my internal the primary video device instead of auto.  Rebooted, and that actually seems like it fixed it using the driver that you mentioned.  Thanks man!

Comment: Now I remember! It was exactly that. I had to select Intel as the primary video device. I am glad you solved it.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I have 4 monitors and the internal vs dedicated was driving me nuts. Swapping nvidia for nouveau drivers did the trick! Reboot and voila!